# CodeIgniter 2, php 5.6 and Nginx returning random content?

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

Recently I have started getting what looks like garbled data as responses for the pages being served up by my CodeIgniter 2 based code. If I put a info.php page in, then the page comes back correctly.

The server is running Nginx 1.6.2 on a Raspbian based host, running PHP 5.6 (PHP Version 5.6.29-0+deb8u1).

I have rolled back my code changes, of my project, to the last good version, but that does not seem to solve the issue. Compression is off in the CI2 configuration for the project.

The php section of the config for the virtual host is:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    # added to try to fix the garbled response, no change
    gzip off;
}
```

The HTTP response, once gzip is specified to be off is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Sat, 25 Feb 2017 00:34:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

I have tried rebooting the host, restarting the Nginx, the php5-fpm and I am currently at a loss. I reinstalled php5-fpm.

An example of the random garbled data:

[image: Example of the garbled data]

Does anyone have any ideas what I should be looking at to solve this issue?

Comment: Check if it is caused by CI gzipping pages itself, e.i. `$config['compress_output']` setting.

Comment: It was set to false, turns out some files got corrupted somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was due to some corrupt files.

I worked this out by moving aside the current project and do a new `git clone`, and then tried accessing the page again and it was rendering correctly. Doing a `diff` revealed a number of files in the problem project as containing apparent garbage. Git didn't flag these files as modified.

On a copy of the corrupt project I saw that I could have tried the following to resolve the issue:

```
git reset --hard
```

This resolved it, but on the original it did not. The only way to get this fixed on the original was to 'touch' all the files:

```
find . -exec touch {} \;
git reset --hard
```

Not sure if this was something to do with Git or a filesystem issue, since this is on an SD card, but things are now resolved.